# Closing EASession Issue | External Accessory

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, external-accessory

I have opened a session then i have opened the input and output streams on different thread. This is little different from EADemo because in EADemo input and output streams are opened on main thread. Which is why streams are not getting closed when i am closing them on close session.

When i am closing the session , session is not closing properly and that's why opening session again causing below issue

`ERROR - opening session failed`
`ERROR - /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/ExternalAccessory/ExternalAccessory-353.22.1/EASession.m:-[EASession dealloc] - 141 unable to close session for _accessory=0x170009ee0 and sessionID=65536`

I have read about it, people are suggesting, if streams are open then session will not get closed. So to close the session properly close the streams.

I am attaching image of my code, please let me know if you need the code also.

[image]

```
-(void)closeSession { 
    if (_session != nil) {
        sessionOpen = false;
        [[_session inputStream] close];
        [[_session inputStream] removeFromRunLoop:inputRunLoop forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
        [[_session inputStream] setDelegate:nil];

        [[_session outputStream] close];
        [[_session outputStream] removeFromRunLoop:outputRunLoop forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
        [[_session outputStream] setDelegate:nil];
        [_mCommunicationThread cancelThread];
        _mCommunicationThread = nil;
        _session = nil;
        _writeData = nil;
        _readData = nil;
       NSLog(@"session closed"); 
    }
}


-(BOOL)openSession {
    [_accessory setDelegate:self];

    if (_session == nil) {
        _session = [[EASession alloc] initWithAccessory:_accessory forProtocol:_protocolString];
        if (_session) {
            NSLog(@"session created");
            inputReadThread = [[NSThread alloc]initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(inputThreadStart:) object:_session];
            [inputReadThread start];
            [inputReadThread setThreadPriority:1];
            if ([inputReadThread isFinished]) {
             //   NSLog(@"inputReadThread is finished");
            }

            outputThread = [[NSThread alloc]initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(outputThreadStart:) object:_session];
            [outputThread start];
            [outputThread setThreadPriority:1];
            if ([outputThread isFinished]) {
               // NSLog(@"inputReadThread is finished");
            }
        }
        else {
            //NSLog(@"creating session failed");
        }
    }
    return (_session != nil);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you ever get anywhere with this?